# EditText error icon and show password missplaced

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText as password input like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

It's working, but when there's an error the error icon shwon twice and it's on top of show password icon.

[image: error icon missplaced]

My validation code to show the error :

```
if (success) {
    finish();
    startMainActivity();
} else {
         mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: post your validation code.

Comment: I've update my post

Comment: what is "success" variable and where did u get it from?

Comment: what is mPasswordview? is it edittext or inputlayout?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Don't call `setError` on the `EditText`, use `TextInputLayout`'s [setError()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: it's worked thanks, I just use the code template from Android Studio to create LoginActivity

Comment: @Lyan Dwi Pangestu:  can you post the code that you got to work?  I am dealing with a similar issue and would appreciate seeing how you solved your problem.

Comment: @AJW as ianhanniballake said, don't call setError on the EditText, use the TextInputLayout's setError, it will show error message below the editText and will looks nice

Comment: @Lyan Dwi Pangestu if you have a minute can you look at my output here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360632/android-why-is-seterror-message-causing-view-distortion  I am trying to use the EditText so that I can keep the popup message box.  Would appreciate any help you could provide.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have a similar problem and am trying to preserve the use of the setError() on the EditText so that I can keep the popup error message box.  Are you able to provide any assistance on this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360632/android-why-is-seterror-message-causing-view-distortion

Comment: @AJW - `TextInputLayout` implements the [Material design text input error spec](https://material.google.com/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors) and does not allow deviating. You'll have to stop using `TextInputLayout` if you want to ignore the guidelines.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I think this is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221465). If the OP wants to use the `setError` method from the `EditText` he should remove the `EditText` from inside the `TextInputLayout` after update 24+.

Comment: @dum4ll3 using `setError` on the `EditText` won't provide a material design compliant error text (that's why you'd use `TextInputLayout` in the first place). Just don't call `setError` on your `EditText` at all.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I got your point regarding compliance. But I think that the issue here is that a widget stopped working correctly, not compliance. I understand that Google has its Material Designs Guidelines. But it is guidelines not laws. So, if I think that is better to use the `EditText.setError()` method it should work correctly. Otherwise it shouldn't be available in the framework. This is a defect.

Comment: @dum4ll3 - calling `setError` on your `EditText` was never the correct thing to do when you use `TextInputLayout`. You can certainly use `EditText`'s `setError` without `TextInputLayout`, but that's not going to give you the same result.

Answer (score 11):

Same behavior for material version 1.1.0-alpha10, even if you set an error into TextInputLayout. You can avoid it by adding to the TextInputLayout this line :

app:errorIconDrawable="@null"

Comment: If you want to hide the error icon so that the eye is still displayed and be able to still set the error description this is the answer you need :)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I've needed. @TylerTurnbull I approve this. :)

Answer (score 3):

please add these two lines in edittext

```
android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
android:paddingRight="40dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code, you can remove toggle while showing the error. you can show toggle while user writing anything. Don't remember, you should give id to text input layout

```
public void showError(){
    password.setError(errorMessage);
    password.requestFocus();
    textInputLayout.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(false);
}


 password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                textInputLayout.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```java
private static Drawable error;

error = getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.nameOfIcon);

// use set bounds, here we use this to remove overlapping between error icon and password toggle.

error.setBounds(-50,0,0,error.getIntrinsicHeight());

//  error icon will show 50dp from right

editTextName.setError("error string",error);
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that it is a bug after updating gradle dependencies to 24+.
Please, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39838839/3174309) answer. I had all my `setError()` working fine before that. Plus, you hadn't to ask for focus in order to display the error.

Answer (score -1):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
  android:paddingEnd="40dp"
  android:inputType="textPassword"
/>
```