# Duplicate error icon on TextView/TextInputEditText

Tags: android

**Details at the end on how the duplicate question doesn't solve this question**

Whenever I set an eror for a TextInputEditText, the error icon and error message are shown correctly.

[image: Error shown after hitting the button with an incorrect password]

However, whenever that field loses focus (by closing the keyboard or selecting the other field, a second error icon appears in the middle of the field, and it doesn't go away until I edit that field

[image: Second error icon]

Here are the fields layout files:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is what I'm using to set the error:

```
private TextInputEditText mRegisterPasswordView;
//[...]
mPasswordView = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
//[...]
mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
mPasswordView.requestFocus();
```

I've looked at examples of the use of setError, and it doesn't seem like I'm doing anything different, I haven't found any results of people having the same error.

I'm using build tools 24.0.2.

The question may be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313026/edittext-error-icon-and-show-password-missplaced), but the expected result is different. If I set the error to TextInputLayout, I get this:

[image: Error shown under field]

(Also, where does that pink color come from?)

Comment: Seems like bug in last design lib. Use 24.1.1