# Android: why is setError message causing View distortion?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have two versions of an app I'm working on.  The first version has a setError message that is set on an EditText UI line if the user tries to save data and the line is empty.  The gradle dependencie uses version 24.0.0.

The message appears correctly as:

[image]

The second version of the app has the same setError code but the View looks distorted because it looks like the Edit Text line has been pushed down by the View so it no longer directly below the "Do" text and the red circular exclamation point is moved down to the left of the error message.  This version uses the gradle dependencie version 24.2.0.

[image]

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Per Mike M's comment below, I used the setError() on the TextInputLayout but that results in a completely different error message that shows up below the beginning of the EditText line that I'd rather not use:

[image]

Activity.java

```
...
public void onClickSave(View v) {
    int stringTD = EditText.getText().toString().replace(" ", "").length();
    if (stringTD == 0) {
        EditText.requestFocus();            
        EditText.setError("Add a Do Item");
```

layout.xml

```
...
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/TD_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FloatingLabel"  >

<com.EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/24dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/24dp"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:maxLength="51"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/DEditText" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText error icon and show password missplaced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313026/edittext-error-icon-and-show-password-missplaced)

Comment: @Mike M.  Using setError() on the TextInputLayout loses the exclamation point and the grey error message dialog box.  It adds a message in red under the EditText line that I'd rather not use.  So I'm looking to see how to correct the usage of the setError() on the EditText

Comment: I rolled the gradle dependency version back from 24.2.0 to 24.0.0 and the problem disappeared.  Perhaps there is a bug in the new dependency version that does not allow proper display of the setError()  with an EditText.  Is it easy to post a request with Google to test for this?

Comment: You could [file an issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) for it. They'll most likely want a complete, minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221465), if you use an `EditText` inside a `TextInputLayout` this kind of behavior occurs after version 24+. So the solution right now would be to use the `EditText` alone.

Try it and see if it works.